# Cant connect to web socket of Hasura PostGreSQL docker container

Tags: ios, docker, graphql, apollo, hasura

We need a realtime database which we can deploy using docker.

I found a Hasura/PostGreSQL docker container which looks like we can use it for our purpose:
https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/getting-started/docker-simple.html

One thing I figured out was that the URL in the documentation was wrong. It's `http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql` and not `http://localhost:8080/graphql`.

But I can't seem to get any results from my subscription...
I get a BAD_ACCESS crash in the package's SplitNetworkTransport.swift

[image: crash]

Am I missing something?

My Apollo client code looks like this:

```
import Apollo
import ApolloWebSocket

class Apollo {
    static let shared = Apollo()

    let client: ApolloClient = {
        let authPayloads = [ "x-hasura-admin-secret": "secret" ]
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = authPayloads

        let wsEndpointURL = URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/v1alpha1/graphql")!
        let endpointURL = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/v1alpha1/graphql")!

        let map: GraphQLMap = authPayloads
        let websocket = WebSocketTransport(request: URLRequest(url: wsEndpointURL), connectingPayload: map)

        let httpNetworkTransport = HTTPNetworkTransport( url: endpointURL,  session: URLSession(configuration: configuration))

        let splitTransport = SplitNetworkTransport(httpNetworkTransport: httpNetworkTransport, webSocketNetworkTransport: websocket)

        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: splitTransport)
    }()
}
```

And I'm calling it as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Apollo

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var subscription: Cancellable?
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.subscription = Apollo.shared.client.subscribe(subscription: MySubscriptionSubscription()) { [weak self] result in
            guard let this = self else { return }

            switch result {
                case .success(let graphQLResult):
                    if let data = graphQLResult.data {
                        this.label.text = "data"
                        print("Simon Says data: \(data)")//TODO: Remove
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    this.label.text = "error"
                    print("Simon Says error: \(error)")//TODO: Remove
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        self.subscription?.cancel()
    }
}
```

P.s. I'm using Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500), swift 5.1, Apollo swift package 0.20.0 and the docker-compose.yaml from the URL in the Hasura docs linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is NOT using swift package manager and use COCOAPODS instead.